# AttributeError: module 'Foundation' has no attribute 'NSString' error with pyperclip

Tags: python, macos, module, pyperclip

Question - How do I fix my code so I don't get this error? I'd like `output` to be placed in my clipboard buffer (I'm on a Mac)?

What I've tried - Printing `output` to the console works great! I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling via `pip` `pyperclip`.

What I notice - my code doesn't call 'NSString' so I haven't a clue where I've gone astray. `object` is the `<class 'str'>`.

Where might I find helpful documentation on how to solve this sort of problem that might come up in the future?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding: utf-8


import pyperclip

output = f""" 

Below are the titles and a one-sentence summary/meaning/'stinger' of zettel 
I've birthed into existence and their ideas I'm grappling.

"""

# print(output)
# print(type(output))
pyperclip.copy(output)
```

Output

```
(base) ➜  ~ python wiwov1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/will/wiwov1.py", line 79, in <module>
    pyperclip.copy(output)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyperclip/__init__.py", line 659, in lazy_load_stub_copy
    return copy(text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyperclip/__init__.py", line 136, in copy_osx_pyobjc
    newStr = Foundation.NSString.stringWithString_(text).nsstring()
AttributeError: module 'Foundation' has no attribute 'NSString'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to reinstall `pyperclip`:

```
pip uninstall pyperclip
pip install --upgrade pyperclip
```

Also I would update the code:

```
import pyperclip

output = "Below are the titles and a one-sentence summary/meaning/'stinger' of zettel \n I've birthed into existence and their ideas I'm grappling."
pyperclip.copy(output)
```

Comment: I had reinstalled pyperclip before, but without `--upgrade` so I did it again with  `-- upgrade`. I then updated the code as you suggest and the problem persists with the same AttributeError.

Comment: Have you also update the code?

Comment: Yes, "I then updated the code". And yet again per your suggestion and I still get the error "AttributeError: module 'Foundation' has no attribute 'NSString'"